# FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to use Spring Boot Devtools in a non Spring Boot (but Spring 4.2) environment, which of course will mean doing some stuff that Spring Boot does. I'm getting the following exception

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.myapp.spring.config.MyAppContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:510)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at com.myapp.spring.config.MyAppContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(MyAppContextLoaderListener.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 22 more

Apr 18, 2016 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
```

here's the ContextListener

```
public class MyAppContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener
{
    private static final String DEFAULT_ACTIVE_PROFILES = "";
    private static final String SERVER_PROPERTIES = "jdbc/serverProperties";
    private static final String SERVER_PROPERTIES_DEFAULTS = "jdbc/serverProperties-defaults";
    private static final String TOMCAT_CONTEXT_NAME = "java:/comp/env/";
    private static final String JETTY_CONTEXT_NAME = "";
    private static final String JETTY_SERVERNAME_TOKEN = "jetty";

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAppContextLoaderListener.class);
    private static final String SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE = "spring.profiles.active";

    public MyAppContextLoaderListener()
    {
    }

    public MyAppContextLoaderListener(WebApplicationContext context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        log.info( "Starting in timezone {}...", TimeZone.getDefault().getID() );
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        String activeProfiles = System.getProperty(SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE, null);
        if(activeProfiles == null){

            activeProfiles = lookupActiveProfiles(event);
        }

        log.info("Setting " + SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE + "=" + activeProfiles);
        System.setProperty(SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE, activeProfiles);

        super.contextInitialized(event);

        log.info(String.format("started in %s Seconds.", TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(System.nanoTime() - start)));
    }

    private String lookupActiveProfiles(ServletContextEvent event)
    {
        String activeProfiles = DEFAULT_ACTIVE_PROFILES;

        boolean isJetty = event.getServletContext().getServerInfo().contains(JETTY_SERVERNAME_TOKEN);
        String name = (isJetty ? JETTY_CONTEXT_NAME : TOMCAT_CONTEXT_NAME);
        Context context = null;
        try
        {
            context = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup(name);
        }
        catch (NamingException ex)
        {
            log.error("Couldn't configure profiles from jndi", ex);
        }

        if (context != null)
        {
            try (FileReader serverPropertiesDefaults
                    = new FileReader(convertToFileName(context, SERVER_PROPERTIES_DEFAULTS));
                FileReader serverProperties = new FileReader(convertToFileName(context, SERVER_PROPERTIES)))
            {


                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.load(serverPropertiesDefaults);
                properties.load(serverProperties);

                activeProfiles = properties.getProperty(SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE, DEFAULT_ACTIVE_PROFILES);

            }
            catch (NamingException | IOException e)
            {
                log.error("Couldn't configure profiles from jndi", e);
            }
        }
        return activeProfiles;
    }

    private String convertToFileName(Context context, String name) throws NamingException
    {
        //strip off the "file:"
        return ((String)context.lookup(name)).substring(5);
    }

}
```

What is it looking for?

**update**

I have found this nested class

```
JerseyAutoConfiguration...

@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public static final class JerseyWebApplicationInitializer
        implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        // We need to switch *off* the Jersey WebApplicationInitializer because it
        // will try and register a ContextLoaderListener which we don't need
        servletContext.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "<NONE>");
    }

}
```

which I thought was disabled by this code that I added

`@EnableAutoConfiguration( exclude = JerseyAutoConfiguration.class )
public class WebConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer`

but it does not appear to be, how can I disable this initializer?

Comment: Could you post the source code of `com.myapp.spring.config.MyAppContextLoaderListener`?

Answer (score 0):

So of course not supported, but the answer is that `JerseyAutoConfiguration` is still being loaded. It's WebInitializer is the highest priority and is loaded even if you exclude the autoconfiguration. Note: we don't use Jersey there's a standard api class that will cause this to load too.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5740